# get one stored procedure value in to result of another stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a stored procedure like this:

```
alter procedure [dbo].[fetchkey]
@locid int =null
as
begin
 select t.TBarcode,t.Status
from Transaction_tbl t 
left join EmployeeMaster_tbl e on t.Ecode=e.Ecode where Locid=5
end
```

my output

```
TBarcode             Status
-------------------- -----------
57173621345          0
57173865238          1
57181456325          2
57182756600          3
58125323124          4
-----------------------------------
```

i have another store procedure to fetching keylocation based on the status:

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[Keylocation]
@Carid nvarchar(50)
as
begin
SET NOCOUNT ON;
SELECT 
        t.Status,
        k.HBarcode,
        te.UniqueName,
     COALESCE(e.Ename, e1.Ename) AS EName
FROM    Transaction_tbl t
        left JOIN UserMaster_tbl u
            ON u.uid = t.PAICID
             left join EmployeeMaster_tbl e on e.ECode=u.Ecode
            AND t.Status = 0
        LEFT JOIN EmployeeMaster_tbl e1
            ON e1.ECode = t.ECode
            AND t.Status = 1 or e1.Ecode=t.DelEcode and t.Status=4
            left Join KHanger_tbl k
            on t.transactID=k.transactid
            and t.Status in(2,3)
            left JOIN Terminals_tbl te ON k.tid = te.tid

WHERE   t.TBarcode = @Carid
end
```

My out put like this:

```
Status      HBarcode         UniqueName                EName                         
3           001              Key Room-1                NULL
```

this is the result of status 3.in my first stored procedure i want to get one more column based on this result.my expected out put:

```
TBarcode             Status    key location
-------------------- -----------
57173621345          0         with Employee(Ename Value)
57173865238          1         with Paic(Ename value)
57181456325          2         UniqueName value( HBarcode value)                       
57182756600          3          UniqueName value ( HBarcode value) 
58125323124          4          with driver(Ename Valu)
```

is there any way to do this? am new in stored procedure.is there any way to  create function and call this result to my stored procedure,,if any one know please help me

Comment: easy solution: make another sproc merging (joining) the queries

Comment: you can do the same as in your last question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17802387/write-stored-procedure-inside-the-other-stored-procedure

Comment: sir..i am new in stored procedure..could you please show once..

Comment: Sir..how i can make another sproc and merging(joining).can u please show once

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at Table valued functions, this can be used to serve out output of one function as input to another store procedure.
This is one of the simplest links explaining it, see here [Table Valued Functions](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/167399/Using-Table-Valued-Functions-in-SQL-Server)

Please see below for your case. I am not sure on what the Join should be made but if you look and understand how it is written you will surely get the idea.

```
CREATE FUNCTION FetchKEY(@locid int)    
 RETURNS @keydetails TABLE  (TbarCode int NOT NULL,    Status int NOT NULL )  AS 
  BEGIN   
     INSERT INTO @person (TbarCode,Status)  select t.TBarcode,t.Status from
     Transaction_tbl t  left join EmployeeMaster_tbl e on t.Ecode=e.Ecode
     where Locid=@locid     
  RETURN; 
  END;
Go
```

So your Store procedure would be like this

```
 ALTER procedure [dbo].[Keylocation] @Carid nvarchar(50) as begin 
 SET NOCOUNT ON; 
 SELECT 
          t.Status,k.HBarcode,
          te.UniqueName,
       COALESCE(e.Ename, e1.Ename) AS EName FROM    Transaction_tbl t
          left JOIN UserMaster_tbl u
              ON u.uid = t.PAICID
               left join EmployeeMaster_tbl e on e.ECode=u.Ecode
              AND t.Status = 0
          LEFT JOIN EmployeeMaster_tbl e1
              ON e1.ECode = t.ECode
              AND t.Status = 1 or e1.Ecode=t.DelEcode and t.Status=4
              left Join KHanger_tbl k
              on t.transactID=k.transactid
              and t.Status in(2,3)
              left JOIN Terminals_tbl te ON k.tid = te.tid  
         **Inner Join FetchKEY F on F.TbarCode = k.HBarcode**      
  WHERE   t.TBarcode = @Carid 
end
```

Comment: I wil check and let u know